# How to resolve unc paths via a C# Process Class?

Tags: c#, command-line

I have the following snippet of code:

```
    private XDocument CreateXmlForMediaFile(string mediaFilePath)
    {
        var args = string.Format("-f {0} --Output=XML", mediaFilePath);

        var miProcess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                Arguments = args,
                FileName = _mediaInfoPath, // path to where MediaInfo.exe is located.
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            }
        };
        // create and instantiate a new xdocument that contains our results for the current manifest.
        miProcess.Start();
        var newXDoc = XDocument.Load(miProcess.StandardOutput);

        return newXDoc;
    }
```

Whenever

> mediaFilePath = local path = a full fledged xml document is returned.
>
> e.g C:\temp\input\ABC001.mp3

But

> mediaFilePath = unc path, on a server somewhere = empty xml document is returned.
>
> e.g \\w2k-testharness\SAMI Testdata\CarrierBased\ABC001.mp3

So basically whats going on here from what I can tell is that when MediaInfo is launched via a process object in c#, it is not resolving network paths properly as when the media file is local, a large xml document is returned and if that files happens to NOT be local then we get an empty looking xml document.

Lastly, I am using File.Exists(...) to verify that each file exists or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a simple case of spaces in UNC paths - = |

The c# code was sound. It turns out that if your accessing a network resource via UNC path via an application, i.e a c# command line application, internal or not, and your UNC path is passed in as a parameter. ***It should be wrapped in double quotes if it has spaces in the path.***

Otherwise without double quotes, your path passed in as a parameter or a hard coded value somewhere, must NOT HAVE ANY SPACES WITHIN IT! OTherwise it will not work.

Comment: You should never, ever pass a path as an argument without quotes. Avoiding quotes is a great way to introduce bugs into a program. Consider yourself lucky if you manage to make your program work without passing those quotes.